# Recently added records cannot be fetched MySQL Python

Tags: mysql, mariadb, mysql-python, mysql-connector

I have a simple program that can add a record and fetch records. If I have two clients connected to the server, when one adds a record for the first time, it works, but successive times, the other cannot fetch it straight away.

```
import mysql.connector
mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
    host="192.168.12.222",
    user = "adminer",
    passwd="",
    database="test"
    )
print(mydb)
dbcursor = mydb.cursor()

dbcursor.execute("SHOW TABLES")
if ('test',) not in dbcursor:
    dbcursor.execute("CREATE TABLE test (itemid INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,name VARCHAR(255), description VARCHAR(255))")
else: print("Table already exists")

a = "a"
while a != "":
    a = input("Enter new name: ")
    if a != "":
        b = "generic description"
        dbcursor.execute("INSERT INTO test (name, description) VALUES (%s, %s)", (a, b))
        mydb.commit()
        print(dbcursor.rowcount, "rows inserted")
        print("Ending position:", dbcursor.lastrowid)

a = "b"
while a != "":
    a = input("Enter ID: ")
    if a != "":
        print(a)
        dbcursor.execute("SELECT * FROM test WHERE itemid = %s", (int(a),))
        result = dbcursor.fetchall()
        print(result)

def deleteEmpty():
    dbcursor.execute("DELETE FROM test WHERE (name = %s OR name IS NULL)", ("",))
    mydb.commit()
```

[image]

Comment: I don't understand your code. Since you use ```UNLOCK TABLES``` there must be also a ```LOCK TABLES``` which I can't find.

Comment: Don't use `LOCK/UNLOCK`, use transactions and Engine=InnoDB.

Comment: Where do I put Engine=InnoDB? The tables on the server are using InnoDB. I have deleted the unlock and it makes no difference to the program.